# Stealing a reference from ConcurrentHashMap before removing it. Correctness

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

`ConcurrentHashMap` does not expose possibility to remove element conditionally and get it. So, I implement it on my own:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, MyClass> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public MyClass removeIfAndGet(UUID key){
    final MyClass[] arr = new MyClass[1];

    return map.computeIfPresent(key, (x, v) -> {
        if(v.isDone()){   // MyClass::isDone is thread-safe
            arr[0] = v;   // let's capture (steal) it!
            return null;  // let's remove it from a map!
        }
        return v;         // v does not satisfy our requirement, don't remove that. 
    });
}
```

Is it ok? I have some doubts because of not nice "stealing" a reference before removing it. Is it safe and correct (also in multithreading terms?). Yes, I know that it is necessary to `MyClass` be thread-safe itself.

P.S. Can I do it better?

Comment: You're never returning/using the 'stolen' object (`arr[0]`). Apart from that, it's a pretty clever solution.

Comment: However, it's hard to tell if what you do is _appropriate_ without more context. Why do you need to get and remove objects which are "done"? How do you determine _when_ they are done? Are you polling the map? Can you wait/notify? Can you use an `ExecutorService` to run and coordinate tasks?

Comment: Do the `isDone()` check and removal of the mapping really have to be atomic w.r.t. the map? I.e. may two threads be concurrently calling `removeIfAndGet(UUID)` with the same UUID?

Comment: @JimmyB, I just need function: `removeIfAndGet`. If we assume that stored values in a map are thread-safe (and no more assumptions), is my approach correct?

Comment: Please see the api documentation for `computeIfPresent()` it will clear your doubts.

Comment: @IrfanBhindawala, it does not

Comment: Looking into the OpenJDK sources, yes, your code is thread safe. The application of the remapping function and removal of an element from the map are atomic w.r.t. the map's other methods.

Comment: @JimmyB, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create your own `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation by overriding the `computeIfPresent()` method and have it retrieving the current mapping, if any. Then, invoke the super implementation (which invokes the parent's computeIfPresent method) and if it that returns null, then return the mapping you have retrieved.

You can take a look on [how computeIfPresent is implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java), and do something similar in your own computeIfPresent method, but instead returning what you want. It can still be thread-safe.

Comment: That approach would no longer be thread-safe. Although I'm not sure if the strict thread-safety of the OP's solution provides any benefit.